# Doctrine query builder: how to do a query with inner joins conditions

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the following entities

- Submission
- SubmissionEvent (status (0,1 or 2), date)

A Submission has a one to many relation with SubmissionEvent. So I'm trying to build a DQL where I can select the last status based on the date of the SubmissionEvent. So what I want is an inner join to submission event but only with the last event.

I tried to use the MAX clause on the inner join but didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    s.name, se.*
FROM Submission s INNER JOIN SubmissionEvent se
        ON s.id = se.submission_id
    INNER JOIN (SELECT submission_id, MAX(event_date) event_date
                FROM SubmissionEvent
                GROUP BY submission_id) t
        ON s.id = t.submission_id
```

Comment: and using the innerJoin method is it posible?

Comment: why not possible? Just give a try

Comment: I mean with doctrinqe query language http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html